# How to make ping less verbose

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch-file, ping

I want to make ping less verbose for my batch script, but I do want it to show time-out messages and other errors.

This is what I've got so far:

```
@echo off

:BEGIN

time /T
ping 127.0.0.0 -n 1 | find "TTL" 
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 | find "TTL"
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 | find "TTL"
sleep 10s

GOTO BEGIN
```

This works, but it is hard to spot the errors on 127.0.0.0 and 1.1.1.1 that give an error message and a time-out message. (I mostly care about the time-out actually).

Is there any way to make `find` filter lines with time out and TTL, or perhaps another trick i can use?

Comment: Well for a start, the sleep command doesn't work, making your script as written behave very badly indeed. Use 'timeout' instead.

Comment: You could always force it to write to a file then filter it that way?

Comment: Yeah, i'll probably end up programming something in a real programming language. Never realised batch scripts where so limited.

Comment: Also, what is wrong with the sleep command? It works just fine here.

Comment: Nvm, sleep seems to be something i have installed here, i'm not sure if it's suposed to be there by default on windows 7, but it wasn't present on my windows vista box.